# From within telnet (putty), can I download a file to my computer?

Tags: unix, ssh, ftp, putty

I generated a key for use with `SSH` (Subversion) on my Unix server, and I need to download the key.

I tried to use an FTP program but the folders are hidden i.e. `/.ssh/`

Can someone download them while in my putty/telnet session?

Comment: `ssh` is not the same as `telnet`. Either fix the title or the tags. Second, most FTP clients have a "show hidden files" option. (FTP is too insecure to be an answer though.)

Answer (score 4):

You can use SCP or SFTP for transferring files over SSH.

But you should be able to do what you need in your ftp client. Look in the client's settings for where you can set the list command, and append "-ah" to the end of it. Your ftp client might even have a setting to display hidden files

Answer (score 4):

You could try using [Le Putty](http://leputty.sourceforge.net/) and do a [ZMODEM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZMODEM) transfer using sz.

Comment: Aren't you a little young to know about zmodem, sonny? +1 for know a client that has it, though.

Comment: Hey now...I've had to blow the dust of some X/ZMODEM once or twice in my career. ;-)

Comment: Sure, but I've got six or seven years on you and most of my peers never used it. 'Course I lived on the trailing edge of the technological curve for a long while...

Comment: Anytime you accidentally blow away the IOS image on a Cisco device.. you'll get to practice your xmodem skillz. Only made that mistake once.. but I've helped others fix theirs since then.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem, I used the copy feature in putty - just select (hilites text) in putty window and you can paste directly into Windows app. This is ok for key files since they will fit in one screen.

If you have a larger amount of text I've resorted to just mailing the file I need to myself

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming since you're using PuTTY, that you're probably running from Windows, and you're connecting over SSH, not Telnet (since you talked about generating an SSH key for SVN). If so, you might want to look into [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php), instead of using FTP to access your data on the remote system. (SCP/SFTP adds in the inherent security of SSH, whereas FTP passes your username and password "in the clear" to the remote system). It's a graphical client that is built on top of the PuTTY source.

Answer (score 1):

Is there something preventing you from copying them to a location from which you can FTP them?

Answer (score 1):

Best to use `sftp` or an `ftp` client that will allow you to display and get hidden files.

But the answer to the question as written is: in the bad-old-days, we used `[xyz]modem` to do this. Putty may even have this technology built in, but you'll need the send client (called `sz` on unix machines) at the far end for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I like the ZModem suggestion, but I'm surprised nobody has suggested **uuencode** yet, which shouldn't require a different SSH client -- assuming most terminal packages can simply log the terminal output to a file.  Even if it can't, short enough files fit on screen and can be copy/pasted to a Notepad window.

So, on the UNIX side, **uuencode** the binary file you want to send, **capture** the terminal's text output of that uuencoding to a text file in Windows, and then **uudecode** that text file on the Windows side to reconstitute the original binary file.  Very primitive, but it works like a charm.

See this Wikipedia article on [Uuencoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuencoding).  I trust you can find uuencode/uudecode utilities as part of the excellent [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) project.

Comment: By the way, if the files are already text, you don't need to uuencode them, just capture or copy/paste.  But I would hope that's obvious :-)

Comment: In addition to the old uuencode, there's the more modern base32 and base64 encodings and you can also use gnupg with ascii armor.  These give you a few options with regard to what character sets the machines have in common.  base32 can be especially useful in some cases because it uses only capital letters.  On Linux the bsd-games (or similarly named) package can go to or from morse code, paper tape, or punch cards which, again, can offer ways around various encoding issues.

Answer (score 0):

For a SSH key specifically, you can probably just make the terminal window larger, `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` and copy the key (by selecting the text) and pasting locally.

For larger, or binary files, look into [`SCP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy#SCP_program) (or `SFTP`)